# Pagination Spring MVC with condition

Tags: spring-mvc

I successfully made a pagination in spring mvc but i want to display only the published articles.. is there any built in in spring that will do that?

```
public Page<Article> getStories(Integer pageNumber) {
    PageRequest request =
            new PageRequest(pageNumber - 1, PAGE_SIZE, Sort.Direction.DESC, "dateUpdated");
    System.out.println(request);
        return frontService.findAll(request);

}
```

i use this code to paginate.

Comment: You can write your own find method to return only the published articles.  How you do that greatly depends on what you are using.  For instance, Spring Data has some crazy PFM that can build finder methods based on an interface and how you name the method.  Since we can't see your code, I can't tell you specifics.

Comment: so you mean, i can make my own inside my repository class? btw. what is pfm?

Comment: Yes, with Spring Data you can make your own find methods.

Comment: What kind of Dao framework do you use? spring-data-jpa , just hibernate, mybatis ? If you use spring-data-jpa, it's very easy to write dao interface for pagination

Comment: thanks for your answers, i used spring-data-jpa, i fixed it already.